# Fire selected row from database gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i want ask you all, about the grid view selected row passing the value from database to another page. Right now my second page capture the id link for example `detail.aspx?id=5` but at the same page i also want to display the all data base on id=5. Because at the first page the data grid view just only display 3 column ,id,name,and detail is link,id and name from database. im now clueless about how i want to implement it hopefully someone can guide me.

```
' cr_number = Request.QueryString("id")
    Label17.Text = cr_number

    Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(strConnectionString)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sqlComm As New MySqlCommand()
            sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn
            With sqlComm
                .CommandText = "select * From cr_record where cr_number=cr_number and Emplid=Emplid"
                Try
                    Dim sqlReader As MySqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()
                    While sqlReader.Read()
                        Label1.Text = sqlReader("isu").ToString()
                        Label2.Text = sqlReader("Emplid").ToString()
                        Label3.Text = sqlReader("Nama").ToString()
                        Label4.Text = sqlReader("DeptDesc").ToString()
                        Label5.Text = sqlReader("JobDesc").ToString()
                        Label6.Text = sqlReader("LocDesc").ToString()
                        Label7.Text = sqlReader("email").ToString()
                        Label8.Text = sqlReader("pnum").ToString()
                        Label9.Text = sqlReader("change1").ToString()
                        Label10.Text = sqlReader("reasonchange").ToString()
                        Label11.Text = sqlReader("problem").ToString()
                        Label12.Text = sqlReader("priority").ToString()
                        Label13.Text = sqlReader("reasondescription").ToString()
                        Label14.Text = sqlReader("systemrequest").ToString()
                        Label15.Text = sqlReader("Status").ToString()
                        Label16.Text = sqlReader("date1").ToString()
                    End While
                Catch ex As MySqlException
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
                sqlConn.Close()
            End With
        End Using
    End Using'
```

here was my latest code @damit

Comment: you can use `HyperLink` http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/09/23/pass-querystring-parameter-with-navigaterurl-in-hyperlink-inside-a-gridview.aspx

Comment: @Damith ok.. now i get the value for 'http://localhost:11870/crm/detail.aspx?cr_number=8&Emplid=001588&Nama=BAHARUDIN%20BIN%20HAMID' but how i want display the data at the second page that will read and display the data capture base on emplid and id

Comment: hope you can get the `string Emplid= Request.QueryString["Emplid"]` in your detail page, then you can get data from database and bind to a gridview, in your select SQL statment put where condition with the value of  `Emplid`

Comment: @Damith tq i get the id but now how i want to display or otherwise to hardcode the display base on the id in myqsl command because now i have error in statememnt

Comment: please update the question with your code and the error details

Comment: @Damith i fix it now my code is working fine with the second page read from database base on ID but when i select the other id, the id is working fine but the detail read from database is same even the ID is diffent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50759/discussion-between-kolapopo-and-damith)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to build the `CommandText` using  `QueryString` value like below

```
.CommandText = "select * From cr_record where Emplid=" & Request.QueryString["Emplid"]
```

best option would be using parameter

```
.CommandText = "select * From cr_record where Emplid=@Emplid"
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emplid", Request.QueryString["Emplid"]);
```

Comment: hehe it was mistake.i forget to add parameters. so i change my code like this Thank alot damith ;)